# Redis: redisClient.auth() says Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am trying to connect to redis service from my node js code something like below in the production:

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');

const redisClient = createClient({
  url: config.redis.url,
});

const connectRedis = async () => {
  try {
    await redisClient.auth().catch((e) => {
      logger.info('ERROR=>', e);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
connectRedis();
```

But it responds with this error: `Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`

My redis config url is something like this: `redis://default:myPassword@127.0.0.1:6379`

Username is not set for redis so I think it is default.
My npm redis version is 4.6

Comment: According to the documentation for the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#usage) package, `redisClient.connect` should be used rather than `redisClient.auth`.

Comment: @ant then it logs this error: ```ERR wrong number of arguments for 'auth' command```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AUTH](https://redis.io/commands/auth/) command allows a connection to authenticate if it didn't when it was created. As one might expect, authentication requires some sort of credentials. In the case of Redis you can provide either a password or  username and a password.

The `.auth` function in Node Redis requires this as well. Here's the code:

```js
/* if you need a username and password */
await redis.auth({ username: 'alice', password: 'foobared' })

/* if you just need a password */
await redis.auth({ password: 'foobared' })
```

That said, your connection string has a username and a password in it. So, it should just work and you shouldn't need to call `.auth`. If your server only needs as password, as you suggest, then your url should be formatted like this:

`redis://:foobared@awesome.redis.server:6380`

If it needs a password, do it like this:

`redis://alice:foobared@awesome.redis.server:6380`

Hope that helps.